# Require script for identify row counts sizes

Tags: sql-server

If I fire delete top 1000 rows,  it will delete them.  But before fire delete command would like know the size of rows and how much storage it will be release from table size.

Answer (score 0):

Size of each row may vary if you have varchar() columns

Best way is to use like below..

```
exec sp_spaceused 'tablename'
```

name        rows    reserved    data    index_size  unused
empsalary   480008  5960 KB     5560 KB 32 KB       368 KB

Divide reserved KB / rows  to get average size of the row